# How to play an .asx file using jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer

How to play an .asx file using jwplayer i googled it  the only flash playing asx file is jwplayer and i am not sure how to do it please help me

Answer (score 0):

This should "just work".

You can see an example of this in action on [LongTail's testing tool page](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/testing/?player=v5&skin=&file=files%2Fasx.xml&height=240&playlist=right&playlistsize=400&width=800). Your embed code would look something like:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="player" name="player" data="../trunk/fl5/player.swf" width="800" height="240">
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="file=files/asx.xml&amp;height=240&amp;playlist=right&amp;playlistsize=400&amp;width=800">
</object>
```

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video